# Adding custom divisions to quadrant chart in anycharts

Tags: node.js, anychart, anychart-8.2

i am using Quadrant Chart from **anychart**.

https://playground.anychart.com/docs/v8/samples/BCT_Quadrant_Chart_04

this allows only four divisions like rightTop, rightBottom, leftTop, leftBottom

i need to generate for nine divisions.
is there any way to generate nine divisions instead of four in anycharts?

[image]

my data im representing in the form of bubbles

divisions should have labels associated with each and scale is also required on x-axis and y-axis

please help me what should i be doing to get this kind of divisions with label and scale.

thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Quadrant chart doesn't support more than 4 divisions, but you can implement the required chart with 9 divisions (3x3 according to your screenshot) with a Scatter chart, bubble series and some specific settings. I have prepared [a sample on AnyCHart Playground](https://playground.anychart.com/HtqiGwwe), this should help you.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help.. it works like the way i wanted.. thanks for the quick help

Comment: any alternative to xGrid() and yGrid()?  im deploying it on heroku, and xGrid yGrid property is not being applied. it works perfectly in local

Comment: No, there's no other workaround. Do you receive any errors in console? Grids should work everywhere

Comment: I am not using AnyChart due to limited budget, but your solution gives me a clue on how to create a 9 quadrant chart using other chart library. Thank you.